# Preventing a custom UITabBarController from changing Tab

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

How can I prevent a tab from being clicked, depending on conditions ? I tried several things and I probably missed some basics.
I'm having an UITabBarCustomController implementing UITabBarController. In the viewDidLoad, depending on a condition, i force the selectedIndex to 1, which works.
Nevertheless, i'm not able to prevent users leaving this tab. I tried to set a UITabBarControllerDelegate on the other ViewController's linked with my UITabBar, where I implemented `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`, and finally i also tried to implement this delegate and method on my custom UITabBarCustomController. But in both cases, when i click on another tab, nothing happens and users are able to access the tab (NSLog in those methods don't show in debug). 

 Any ideas ? thanks.

// Edit : Test code in delegate method :

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"test");
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: what do you have inside the `shouldSelectViewController:` method? (_add the relevant code in your question_)

Comment: I hope you are returning NO in the delegate method for all the other viewController.

Comment: I edited my post. At the moment, even the NSLog doesn't appear in debug. The condition (not shown here) works. @AnindyaSengupta  yes, the method is implemented in every viewController handled by the UITabBarController and is the same for all.

Comment: then you better get that working. ... check if you have set delegate on the `UITabBarController` object (_to **`self`** mostly_) ... just post the UITabBarController .h and .m. Have you done it programmatically or via xib/storyboard?

Comment: @staticVoidMan Nope I didn't :) "missed some basics" uh. Delegate wasn't set in others viewControllers. I added self.tabBarController.delegate = self in them and it works, thanks.

Comment: Actually, I removed the delegate in the Tabs i don't need to block. Having the method only in the Tab i need to block is enough.

Comment: huh... "`removed the delegate in the Tabs i don't need to block`" ... i don't quite follow

Comment: I have 3 tabs, with those at index 0 : XViewController, 1 : YViewController, 2 : ZViewController. I force the landing on the tab with index 1. I only needed to put the delegate in the YViewController in order to block the access on the other tabs.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can stop/prevent Tabbar items to switch your tab on tabbar item click

**For Swift 3.0**

Make sure you have implemented **UITabBarControllerDelegate** and set **UITabbarController**'s ***delegate*** to ***self***

then override this delegate in your controller

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[2] {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```